# 404 custom error page

Tags: html, http-status-code-404

I need to load the sample error page:- for my abc.com site

[image]

I have edited the .htaccess file inside the home directory of the site (say abc) document root is /opt/lampp/htdocs, and gave **ErrorDocument 404 /opt/lampp/htdocs/abc/404.html** this line inside .htaccess file.

But still displaying

[image]

What to do?

Comment: The last screen shot mentions that the file you configured as `ErrorDocument` does not exist.

Comment: Did you try restarting Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [HTTPD documentation for `ErrorDoument`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument), the path to a file must be relative to the configured `DocumentRoot`, ie. if `/opt/lampp/htdocs/abc/404.html` is the file you want to use, and the `DocumentRoot` is set to `/opt/lampp/htdocs`, then you must use `ErrorDocument 404 /abc/404.html`.

If you want to set the `ErrorDocuent` in a `.htaccess` file, you must ensure that `AllowOverride FileInfo` is set for the directory the `.htaccess` file is stored in.

Comment: yeah.. relative path . I got it :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this is a live site have you gone to the Web hosting site? There should be a 404 Error options were you can chose between the standard Error or custom Error page.

Answer (score 1):

fixed this issue on checking the error log. The path was different.

[Thu Sep 12 12:53:18 2013] [error] [client 203.200.152.157] File does not exist: /opt/lampp/htdocs/abc/af;ldkjf

[Thu Sep 12 12:53:18 2013] [error] [client 203.200.152.157] File does not exist: /opt/lampp/htdocs/404.html

I gave this in .htacess and checked:-

**ErrorDocument 404 "/abc/404.html"**

Now the page is loading fine, if we give http://abc.com/anything-ddfsd

[image]

Comment: give relative path from the doc root, to the file in .htaccess **ErrorDocument 404 "/ibericaHost1/404.html"**