# Customize Anchor Tag link not found message?

Tags: html, css, tags, anchor

[image]

How can I customize this message when HTML anchor tag link is not found?

Comment: you'll need to create a custom error page and then configure your server or app to use it

Comment: Probably, duplicate of this question -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759390/404-custom-error-page)